# With Terraform, how to create a google firewall from port to port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have already created firewall (security groups) on AWS using the feature from_port/to_port.
For exemple, here I create a SG from port 5000 to port 5100, from port 6000 to 6100, from port 7000 to 7100 ...

```
variable "list_port" {
    type = "list"
    default = [
    "5000-5100",
    "6000-6100",
    "7000-7100",
  ]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "test" {
  name     = "test"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "test" {
  count             = "${length(var.list_port)}"
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = "${ element(split("-", element(var.list_port, count.index)), 0) }"
  to_port           = "${ element(split("-", element(var.list_port, count.index)), 1) }"
  protocol          = "TCP"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.test.id}"
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with google, but it seems there is no from_to options.
I want to be the more DRY possible and not repeat the ports. An other good reason is that I'm using terraform module with a variable containing ports to open.
So I want to avoid something like that.

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "firewall" {
  name          = "test"
  direction     = "INGRESS"
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = [5000, 5100]
  }
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = [6000, 6100]
  }
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = [7000, 7100]
  }

}
```

Does anyone known a better solution ?

Thanks

BR,

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify port ranges in the array:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "gaming-blacknut" {
    name          = "test"
    direction     = "INGRESS"
    allow {
        protocol = "tcp"
        ports    = ["5000-5100"]
   }
}
```

**Edit**

After seeing your problem I believe you can still use port ranges in the `allow` rules, specifically the variable.

Example:

```
    allow {
        protocol = "tcp"
        ports    = ["${var.list_port}"]  // You may not need the surrounding [ ] as the variable is already defined as a list.
   }
```

You can see an example rule using a list of single ports and a port range in the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_firewall.html).

Comment: Hi @Ewan, you are right. I have too much simplified  my problem. I have edited my question with the real problem

Comment: You are right ! I was seeking a too complicated solution. Very nice ! Thanks @Ewan